# akka http compile error

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I am new in akka framework and now try to setup simple webservice with this framework .
write a simple akka-http application  :

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer

import scala.io.StdIn

object MainRunner extends App {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("mySystem")
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer
  implicit val ec = system.dispatcher

  val route =
    path("hello") {
      get {
        complete("Congratulation , this is your response")
      }
    }

  val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandle(route, "localhost", 8080)

  println(s"Server online at http://localhost:8080/\nPress RETURN to stop...")
  StdIn.readLine() // let it run until user presses return
  bindingFuture
    .flatMap(_.unbind()) // trigger unbinding from the port
    .onComplete(_ => system.terminate()) // and shutdown when done
}
```

receive this error on compile :

```
Error:(34, 44) type mismatch;
 found   : akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route
    (which expands to)  akka.http.scaladsl.server.RequestContext => scala.concurrent.Future[akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteResult]
 required: akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow[akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpRequest,akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpResponse,Any]
  val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandle(route, "localhost", 8080)
```

How can fix that ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is just a simple mistake when instantiating your `ActorMaterializer`:

```
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer
```

should be replaced by

```
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
```

With a valid materializer in scope, the implicit conversion between the `Route` and the `Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, _]` should happen as expected, and the compiler should be happy.

Comment: That's a bummer. We also filed an issue with IntelliJ to warn against these kind of problems: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-12026